How can I get the confidence variable from a CoreML prediction
I am using the CreateML tool to train a text classifier, when I use the preview feature and put in a sentence it will give me a prediction along with a confidence variable
Here is how I am using the model on the app
import CoreML
...

    func predict(phrase:String) -> String {
        guard let rollModel = try? Roll(configuration: MLModelConfiguration()) else {
            return "Failed to load the Roll Model."
        }

        let rollModelInput = RollInput(text: phrase)

        guard let prediction = try? rollModel.prediction(input: rollModelInput, options: MLPredictionOptions()) else {
            return "Roll Model Prediction Failed"
        }
        
        return prediction.label
    }

This is working, it's providing a prediction.
My data is in the standard text/label format
Even when I export the model to xcode and run the preview in xcode the confidence variable is present.
When I run the prediction on the device I want to know what the confidence variable is, how can I get access?


I've been unable to get this to work, I don't get why this link exists, it even says MLTextClassifier, is this just out of date, I don't get why this function isn't showing up for me https://developer.apple.com/documentation/createml/mltextclassifier/predictionwithconfidence(from:)

To best use the text classifiers, you should be utilising NLModel to generate the predictions.
The key is using predictedLabelHypotheses(for:maximumCount:)
Your new code would look a little similar to;
let model: FVCompeitionTextClassifier? = {
    let config = MLModelConfiguration()
    return try? Roll(configuration: config)
}()

func predict(phrase:String) throws -> String {
    let rollModel = try NLModel(mlModel: model!.model)
    
    for labelHypothese in rollModel.predictedLabelHypotheses(for: phrase, maximumCount: 1) {
        print("Label: \(labelHypothese.key), Confidence: \(labelHypothese.value)")
        // Do logic that you need to do ie sort, then return the label you need
    }
    
}


Also don't force unwrap the model in production code
